Is there a name for this looped power combiner circuit topology?
I've encountered a circuit topology that has an interesting effect that is so simple in design that I have a hard time believing that it hasn't been studied and named previously.
Here is a basic diagram of the idea

The process has five steps,

An input sine wave is inserted unidirectionally into the loop.

The wave travels through the loop of transmission lines which have a delay.

At the end of the loop, the travelling wave is combined with the input pulse, constructively interfering to produce an amplified wave.

Steps 2 and 3 are repeated for a time to increase the amplification of the wave.

The switch is thrown, and all power present in the loop exits in one large amplified pulse.


I've done a very basic reproduction of this system in LTSpice using a Wilkinson power divider as the method of combining the input pulse and the end of the loop. I have observed that for a brief moment after the switch is thrown that the power seen at the output is near double that of the input power and then it quickly returns to the steady state.
Originally, there was a research article (that I unfortunately don't have on hand atm) in the terahertz range that employed a version of this setup using right angled mirrors to form the loop and a laser as an input so I know that it has been done to some extent.
My questions are:

Have you ever seen this before? Does it have a name? If possible, any resources available that discuss this more in depth?
Is there any reason that this would fail in real life in the microwave range? What downsides might you anticipate with such a setup?

EDIT:
In my original question my diagram clearly takes some liberties about the physical operation of transmission lines. In reality of course, the transmission lines are bidirectional. From my understanding of transmission lines, the bidirectionality is mainly the problem at the point of power combination. In simulation, I simply used a wilkinson power divider

In the image you can ignore the fact that the PWL gives a switch that is constantly on. That is because I tried both the always on case and the switch thrown at 100ns case. Here is the power at the input (green) versus the power at the output (red, and the "output" is the 50 ohm switch that properly terminates the tline). I'm aware the ltspice simulation isn't perfect (and more testing could be done to optimize the effect) but clearly the moment the switch is thrown the output power has grown to almost twice the input, which shows the effect.


I'd just like to point out that transmission lines work in both directions.

Note that with a little bit of gain, this could be called an oscillator.

That is simply a resonator.
Nothing really special about it; depending on how the combiners/dividers (where you combine the feedback signal into the "forward" signal and where you divide split it off from the end of your lower transmission line) are implemented, this might be a "rat-race coupler", but that would be a special case.
The problem with your idea of "amassing" energy this way is that it's rather hard to build good directive couplers.
Also, your output "discharge switch" idea doesn't work that easily, you need to remember that you want the resonator to be lossless, which puts constraints on the end where your switch is attached, which can't be fulfilled by an open switch and a transmission-line impedance (closed switch) at the same time.
Also, the second transmission line is completely unnecessary; simply let the wave reflect at the end of the first, you already have the magic perfect directive coupler that only lets the wave through in one direction, so for the wave coming from the opposite side, it would look like an open, I guess.
Still, all that happens is that your excitation hits a resonant frequency of your resonator, and the resonance can collect considerable energy.
A resonator is a very well-understood device in both classical electrical networks (see: LC resonator, quality factors of these…) and microwave electronics (cavity resonators, applications of these as power amplifiers in travelling-wave tubes, klystrons etc). It's also a well-understood device in mechanics and civil engineering:


I've added some additional results showing the effect but I see your point in regards to the fact that this boils down to a simple resonance. In fact, if I replaced the transmission lines (or line if I simplified) with an RLGC equivalent then it would probably be a simple matter to identify the best frequency of operation for a given line.

It is a somewhat naive conceptual block diagram.
Transmission lines are bidirectional unlike as shown.
Feedback must be mixed with a controlled impedance at 1GHz, not shorted with inputs with no known combiner method.
The feedback would cause echos with attenuation so the gain, being passive cannot be a continuous oscillation, rather only partial or may act as a wavelength filter.
